# Showing that the eigenvalues of $B$ are all real.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with distinct eigenvalues (that is, $A$ has no repeated eigenvalue). Let $B$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix that commutes with $A.$ Then show that the eigenvalues of $B$ are all real.

I couldn't quite able to do this problem. Could anyone please give me some small hint? I started with some like that $:$

> Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $B$ corresponding to an eigenvector $x$ then we have $$\overline {\lambda}\ \|x\|^2 = \langle Bx, x \rangle = \langle x, B^t x \rangle.$$ But since $A$ is symmetric and $B$ commutes with $A$ hence so is $B^t.$ Using commutativity of $A$ and $B^t$ one can easily show that if $x$ is eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to some eigenvalue $\mu$ then $B^t x$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the same eigenvalue. But eigenspaces of $A$ are all one dimensional and hence this proves that $x$ is also an eigenvector of $B^t.$ Now if we can show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B^t$ corresponding to the eigenvector $x$ we are through. This is where I got stuck.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** By the spectral theorem, all eigenvalues of $A$ are real. Let $x \in \Bbb R^n$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$. Show that $x$ must also be an eigenvector of $B$. You might find it helpful to separately consider the cases where $\lambda \neq 0$ and $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: BenGrossman$:$ please have a look at my edit.

Comment: The fact you mentioned is easy to prove. But then how do I proceed?

Comment: @Rabin Your proof is mostly fine. However, it is not necessarily true that $B^t x$ is an eigenvector; it is also possible that $B^t x = 0$; this needs to be addressed. Also, there is no reason to go from $B$ to $B^t$; you could make the same argument using $B$ instead.

Comment: @Rabin If $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is an eigenvector of a real matrix $B$, then it must hold that the associated eigenvalue is real.

Comment: Why do you need spectral theorem? Eigenvalues of symmetric matrices are all real is an one line argument.

Comment: If $B^t x = 0$ then also $x$ is an eigenvector of $B^t$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0.$

Comment: @Rabin It's quicker to write "by the spectral theorem" then it is to give the one line argument. In any case, it doesn't matter how you arrive at the conclusion that $A$ has real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Rabin That is correct, but it needs to be stated explicitly as a part of your proof. If $B^tx = 0$, then it is not (technically) true that $B^tx$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: But how does it guarantee that the eigenvalues are all real. If the eigenvectors are in $\mathbb R^n$ is it necessary that the corresponding eigenvalues should be real? Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Yes. If $x$ is a non-zero real vector and $\lambda$ is a scalar such that $\lambda x$ is real, then $\lambda$ must be a real number.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. How stupid I am. This is so easy. Because if $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ then $Bx$ and $x$ are both in $\mathbb R^n$ and hence the corresponding eigenvalue should be real. Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: @Rabin You have nothing to apologize for. I'm glad it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is real symmetric with distinct eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors. So
$$
A=U^TDU
$$
where $U\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and
$U^TU=I$ and $D$ is diagonal with distinct real elements. Hence
$$
AB=BA \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad U^TDUB=BU^TDU
$$
and hence
$$
DUBU^T=UBU^TD
$$
If $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$,
$L=UBU^T=(L_{ij})$, then $LD=DL$, and for $i\ne j$,
$$
d_iLe_i=L(d_ie_i)LDe_i=DLe_i
$$
and hence $Le_i$ is a multiple of $e_i$. (Here $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$.)
Say $Le_i=\lambda_i e_i$. This means that
$$
L=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n).
$$
Hence $B=U^TLU$, If  $v_k\in\mathbb R^n$ is the $k-$column of $U^T$, then
$$
Bv_k=U^TLUv_k=U^TLe_k=\lambda_k U^Te_k=\lambda_kv_k
$$
and therefore
$$
\lambda_k=\langle v_k,Bv_k\rangle\in\mathbb R.
$$